# Confusion with lambda function parameter

Tags: javascript, lambda, settimeout

I'm trying to use setTimeout with a lambda function in a for loop, but it only captures the last parameters for the contents of the lambda function from the final iteration of the for loop. In C# we can make a a new variable to pass as the parameter each time it is passed into a new lambda function, but that doesn't appear to work in javascript. Any clues?

The specific function I'm talking about is setElementsByIdTimed()

```
var gElems = new Array();

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

    //setElementsById('icon_anim_start' , "icon_anim_end");
    //setTimeout(function() {setElementsById('icon_anim_end' , "icon_anim");} , 500);

    var delay = setElementsByIdTimed('icon_anim_start' , "icon_anim_end" , 250);
    setTimeout(function() {setElementsById('icon_anim_end' , "icon_anim");} , delay);
    });

    function getElementsById (elementID){
        var elementCollection = new Array();
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++){
            if(allElements[i].id == elementID)
                elementCollection.push(allElements[i]);

        }
        return elementCollection;
    }

    function setElementsById (elementID, newID) {
        var elems = new Array();
        elems = getElementsById(elementID);

        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        {
            elems[i].id = newID;
        }
    }


    function setElementsByIdTimed (elementID, newID , ms) {
        var elems = new Array();
        elems = getElementsById(elementID);
        console.log("elems.length: " + elems.length);
        gElems = elems;


        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            var index = i
            setTimeout(function() {
                setElementId(index, newID);
            }, ms * i);
        }

        return ms * (elems.length-1);
    }

    function setElementId (index , newID) {
        console.log ("gElems.length: " + gElems.length + "  index: " + index);
        gElems[index].id = newID;
    }
})
```

Comment: This is because javascript is **[function scoped not block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling)**.

Comment: as a side note, I find it disturbing that you'd have multiple elements with the same ID - while it breaks the HTML spec, each to their own I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic JavaScript closure problem. Basically, there is only one instance of the index variable and it's declared outside the context of the lambda function. So every lambda function is using the same index, and they are executed after the loop completes so index looks to be out-of-bounds on every invocation.

To get this to work `index` must have closure scope:

```
function setElementsByIdTimed(elementID, newID , ms)
{
    var elems = new Array();
    elems = getElementsById(elementID);
    console.log("elems.length: " + elems.length);
    gElems = elems;


    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        var index = i
        setTimeout( setClosure(index,newID), ms * i);
    }

    return ms * (elems.length-1);
}
function setClosure( index, newID ) {
    // this lambda is called after the timeout elapses
    return function() {
            setElementId(index, newID);}
}
```

You can also play a self-invocation trick, but it's a little mind-bendy:

```
function setElementsByIdTimed(elementID, newID , ms)
{
    var elems = new Array();
    elems = getElementsById(elementID);
    console.log("elems.length: " + elems.length);
    gElems = elems;


    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        var index = i
        setTimeout( (function(idx,nid) {
                return function () {
                    setElementId(idx,nid);}
            })(index, newID),
            ms * i);
    }

    return ms * (elems.length-1);
}
```

These are effectively the same solution, but the first syntax is probably a lot simpler to grasp.

Comment: Best answer! Thank you. This is clear, it makes sense and it is concise. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        var index = i
        setTimeout(function() {
            setElementId(index, newID);
        }, ms * i);
    }
```

use an IIFE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

```
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        (function(index) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                setElementId(index, newID);
            }, ms * index);
        }(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in

```
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        var index = i
        setTimeout(function() {
            setElementId(index, newID);}, ms * i);
    }
```

index is allways the same variable. Try:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {

        (function(index){
          setTimeout(function() {
            setElementId(index, newID);}, ms * i);
        })(i);
    }
```

each time you must access a variable within a clousure in a loop you must use a function to access it. You can also use a forEach applied to the array:

```
    elems.forEach(function(index){
        setTimeout(function() {
            setElementId(index, newID);}, ms * i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you should also use the map function instead of a for: